# kubernetes minikube faster uptime

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am using minikube and building my projects by tearing down the previous project and rebuilding it with

```
kubectl delete -f myprojectfiles
kubectl apply -f myprojectfiles
```

The files are a `deployment` and a `service`.

When I access my website I get a 503 error as I'm waiting for kubernetes to bring up the deployment. Is there anyway to speed this up? I see that my application is already built because the logs show it is ready. However it stays showing 503 for what feels like a few minute before everything in kubernetes triggers and starts serving me the application.

What are some things I can do to speed up the uptime?

Comment: Is your app "ready"? Do you have readiness probes defined which is not allowing it to take requests?

Answer (score 0):

Configure what is called `readinessProbe`, it won't fasten your boot up time, but it will help you by not giving false sense that application is up and running. With this your traffic will only be sent to your application pod when it is ready to accept the connection. Please read about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/).

FWIW your application might be waiting on some dependency to be up and running, also add these kinda health checks to that dependency pod.

Answer (score 0):

You should not delete your Kubernetes resources. Use either `kubectl apply` or `kubectl replace` to update your project.

If you delete it, the nginx ingress controller won't find any upstream for a short period of time and puts on a blacklist for some seconds.

Also you should make sure, that you use [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) which is able to do a rolling update without any downtime.